# É possível executar comandos CSS em javascript? HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

É possível executar comandos CSS em javascript?

Exemplo, se eu clicasse em um botão, a cor dele alteraria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Claro que sim, praticamente tudo o que acontece no [DOM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_de_Objeto_de_Documentos) consegue controlar/manipular com javascript:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
})
```

```css
#btn {
   background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">CLICA AQUI</button>
```

Pode delegar o [evento no html](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp), neste caso é o `onclick` que é a sintaxe do evento click como atributo de html:

```js
function change_color(ele) {
    ele.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; 
}
```

```css
button {
   background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change_color(this);">CLICA AQUI</button>
<button onclick="change_color(this);">CLICA AQUI</button>
<button onclick="change_color(this);">CLICA AQUI</button>
```

Ou, muitas vezes isto é da minha preferência, podemos adicionar/remover as classes que estilizam os elementos:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    if(btn.classList.contains('green')) {
       btn.className = "";
       return;
    }
    btn.className = "green";
})
```

```css
button {
   background-color: red; 
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">CLICA AQUI</button>
```

Nestes casos o unico elemento/atributo manipulado é o do botão/cor do fundo.

Isto são meros exemplos, básicos, que que lhe podem dar uma ideia das possiblidades (tudo que faz nos css pode fazer em js, e mais ainda).

Answer (score -1):

Com esses recursos, é possível então controla itens de menus e submenus, criados com UL e LI, devidamente identificados por classes?
Se quiserem anexar um pequeno exemplo, ficaria grato, sou iniciante na área.

Obrigado.

Comment: Vitor e Miguel, primeiramente lhes peço desculpa pela demora em responder, acabei dando um tempo no meu aprendizado e esqueci que havia postado aqui. Obrigado pela ajuda, estou recomeçando os estudos e as dicas que postaram serão meu ponto de partida.