# Atribuir CSS no jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte código, como faço para atribuir um display: block dentro do jquery ?, porque quero que apareça os campos sem precisar clicar em "adicionar", ele apareça automatico a quantidade, conforme eu determinei no `if($("tr.linhas").length < 3){`

Segue link para visualização: https://jsfiddle.net/hgoc4p9v/

Comment: Dê uma aolhadela aqui Caroline: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147413/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-executar-comandos-css-em-javascript-html/147415#147415

Comment: Ainda não consegui encaixar o display block :/, como sou nova, nao sei se faz diferença do Jquery para o Javascript, sabe me dizer ?

Comment: Se estiver a ir por javascript nativo: `ele.style.display = 'block';`, se quiser fazer com jquery `$(ele).css('display', 'block');`. `ele` é o elemento a alterar

Comment: Perfeito, ja deu uma luz na sintaxe , valeu

Comment: :) de nada, boa sorte

Comment: Cara sem querer abusar, rsrs, mas nao consegui atribui essa sintaxe no codigo, poderia me explicar melhor onde eu poderia colocar esse elemento ?