# problema com tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, table

Gostaria de saber se é possível manipular a pesquisa do `tablesorter`?

Tenho uma lista com vários registros e páginas, porem quando mando pesquisar, só é pesquisado pela pagina.

Como faço para pesquisar em toda a tabela?

Segue o código do `tablesorter`:

```js
 <script>
    $(function(){
      
      $('table > tbody > tr:odd').addClass('odd');
      
      $('table > tbody > tr').hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('hover');
      });
      
      $('#marcar-todos').click(function(){
        $('table > tbody > tr > td > :checkbox')
          .attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))
          .trigger('change');
      });
      
      $('table > tbody > tr > td > :checkbox').bind('click change', function(){
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
        if($(this).is(':checked')) $(tr).addClass('selected');
        else $(tr).removeClass('selected');
      });
      
      $('form').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
      
      $('#pesquisar').keydown(function(){
        var encontrou = false;
        var termo = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('table > tbody > tr').each(function(){
          $(this).find('td').each(function(){
            if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(termo) > -1) encontrou = true;
          });
          if(!encontrou) $(this).hide();
          else $(this).show();
          encontrou = false;
        });
      });
         
      $("table").tablesorter({
          dateFormat: 'uk',
          
   sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]
          
        }) 
        .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")})
        .bind('sortEnd', function(){
          $('table > tbody > tr').removeClass('odd');
          $('table > tbody > tr:odd').addClass('odd');
        });
      
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Nunca usei, mas dê uma olhadela na documentação, pode ser que ajude: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: não tem nada na documentação sobre isso.

Comment: Ainda não consegui resolver. Alguém sabe como? Obrigada.

Comment: Pode ver aqui: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html . Eu nunca fiz nada com este plugin, não consigo ajudar. Se tiver liberdade para isso pode sempre experimentar outro plugin, ex: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Eu tentei usar o datatables mas me pareceu muito confuso, não conseguia alterar o layout para se adequar ao meu. Sabes me dizer se tem como modificar layout?

Comment: Só com JS, tens de ver na consola quais os elementos que queres alterar e depois de chamares a função que cria a tabela e que podes alterar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147413/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-executar-comandos-css-em-javascript-html/147415#147415